# Removing common elements between two different Arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have read several posts for this but not getting the exact thing I am looking for. I know how to develop a complex logic for this, this is for Android and we can't expect too much processing on the device due to the limited resources available.

I have an ArrayList of an bean class objects consisting five fields as

Java Bean -- MyShares

1. fileName
2. filePath
3. fileSize
4. isShared
5. Creator

I have another ArrayList of String which contains only filepaths. Now what I want is to remove all the common elements between the two arraylist means the file paths in seconds arraylist and file path in first arraylist objects are similar then I have to remove from both of the arraylist but I don't want a new arraylist which contains the uncommon elements. But I want to get my both arraylist only without their common elements.

Comment: What you tried so far ? Show us .

Comment: What about using a Set instead of a List?

Comment: @Achintya Jain okkk Just wait

Comment: @krishna But one of my arraylist consists of an bean objects which has 5 fields and I have to compare only one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Map` from `String` to your object type (I used `Obj` in order to make a SSCCE).

Assume we are given a list `objects` and a list `strings`.

Steps:

1. Put all `objects` in a `map` with their `str` variable as key
2. Get all those `str` variables using `map.keySet()`
3. Get all strings that are in `objects` but not in `strings` by `keys.removeAll(strings)`
4. Get all strings that are in `strings` but not in `objects` by `strings.removeAll(keys)`
5. Get the `objects` that correspond to the remaining `keys`

Note that you need to be careful in steps 3 and 4, because you need to back up one of the collections.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        List<Obj> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        objects.add(new Obj("a"));
        objects.add(new Obj("b"));
        objects.add(new Obj("c"));

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("a");
        strings.add("d");
        strings.add("e");

        remove(objects, strings);

        System.out.println(objects);
        System.out.println(strings);
    }

    public void remove(List<Obj> objects, List<String> strings) {
        Map<String, Obj> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Obj object : objects) {
            map.put(object.str, object);
        }

        Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
        List<String> oldStrings = new ArrayList<>(strings);

        strings.removeAll(keys);
        keys.removeAll(oldStrings);

        objects.clear();
        for (String key: keys) {
            objects.add(map.get(key));
        }       
    }

    public class Obj {  
        public String str;
        public Obj(String str) {
            this.str = str;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return str;
        }       
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
[b, c]
[d, e]
```

Answer (score 2):

Rough Java code:

```
HashSet<String> commonKeys = new HashSet();
for (Share share : shares) {
    commonKeys.add(share.filePath);
}
commonKeys.retainAll(filePaths);
for (Iterator<Share> it = shares.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Share share = it.next();
    if (commonKeys.contains(share.filePath)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
filePaths.removeAll(commonKeys);
```

This won't be `O(N)` because `remove` on an `ArrayList` is expensive.  To get `O(N)` behavior you either need to create new `ArrayList` instances, or add the elements you don't want removed to temporary lists, and then `clear()` and add them back into the original lists.

Answer (score 2):

I will go with some clues for you

Suppose you have **two lists** one for bean objects namely **myBeans** and another for filePaths namely **filePaths**

```
List<MyBean> beansToRemove = new ArrayList<MyBean>();
List<FilePath> filePathsToRemove = new ArrayList<FilePath>();

for(Bean myBean : myBeans) {
    for(FilePath filePath : filePaths) {
        if(myBean.getfilePath.equals(filePath.getFilePath())) {
            beansToRemove.add(myBean);
            filePathsToRemove.add(filePath);
        }
    }
}

//Now remove filePaths and beans if any

for(Bean myBean : beansToRemove) {
    myBeans.remove(myBean);
}

for(FilePath filePath : filePathsToRemove) {
    filePaths.remove(filePath);
}
```

it is just a flow to make you clear for what to do; you can further customize it according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an outer loop to scan over the Bean objects, and an inner loop to scan over the file paths.

pseudo code:

```
for (Bean i in beans) {
    for (String p in paths) {
        if (i.path.equals(p)) {
            beansToRemove.add(i);
            pathsToRemove.add(p);
        }
    }
}
beans.removeAll(beansToRemove);
paths.removeAll(pathsToRemove);
```

I'm not sure if my extra arraylists to track the removed arraylists go against your question or not since the original arrays remain. 
If you presort both arrays on the path and keep track of the position in each area (not exhaustive search) you can improve it from n2 to nlgn